# Tricky circuit analysis problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductance

[image]

My question is regarding the two coils present in the circuit. Their turns ratio was given but I can't see where I can use that information. I did come up with a full set of linear equations which can be solved to yield the voltage U2, however that voltage will obviously depend on R,k, and the inductances L1,L2, and the mutual inductance M. Is there a way to use the given information and find M using N1/N2?

Comment: Given just turns ratio, and not knowing the inductances, can this be analyzed?

Answer (score 2):

You should treat the two inductances as an ideal transformer,

$$\frac{U_{L_1}}{U_{L_2}}=\frac{N_1}{N_2}=m.$$